# Output result of time command to variable in bash script

Tags: shell-script

I know that similar questions to this have been asked, but I haven't found one that addresses my situation closely enough...

I need to time a command in a bash script, similar to this:

```
mytime="$(time ( ls ) 2>&1 1>null)"
rm null
```

This works fine. But when I try to replace `ls` with something more complicated, I run into issues:

```
command="$reg 1d_euler_2nd.rg -nc $nc -ll:cpu $np -ns $nstop"
mytime="$(time ( $command ) 2>&1 1>null)"
rm null
```

where `reg` is an environment variable and `nc`, `np`, and `nstop` are all defined in my script. I get the following error when I try to use this code:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My apologies -- as I was trying to create a minimal working example, I realized that the problem was elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Do you do something with the file `null` before you delete it or do you just mix it up with `/dev/null`? What does "where reg is an environment variable" mean? What is the content?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal example of the code that still experiences the problem. It's not clear right now what `reg`, `nc` etc. might contain.

Comment: And please run your code through `bash -vx script.sh` and add the output to your question. I am not sure which program produces the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to capture the output of `time` separately just fine with a subshell *without* using a variable to abstract a command.  A simple example for brevity:

```
$ time ( echo "Hello" > example.out 2> example.err ) > time.out 2> time.err
$ ls *{out,err}
example.err example.out time.err    time.out
$ cat time.err

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ cat example.out
hello
```

Comment: Impressive. Is that a shell bug? :-o

Comment: Nope; that's the shell working as intended.  `time`'s diagnostic output goes to standard error, but if you don't want that commingled with the standard error of your actual job, you need to first capture _its_ standard error, which in my example is taken care of in the redirects within the subshell.